# Is a moving stress possible in numbers with -teen?

Tags: pronunciation

Does the stress depend upon the word that follows or precedes the number with -teen?

i.e. Is it correct to say **THIR**teen pages instead of thir**TEEN** pages?

Comment: Are you talking about conversation? The number is usually slightly more emphasized here, but I can't speak for other countries.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, I just want to know I got it right - the stress can move depending on the situation.

Comment: Yes. I can't find a resource that describes this now, but here's a blog post by John Wells that confirms that the phenomenon exists: "The teen numerals are all lexically double-stressed, and therefore susceptible to ‘stress shift’ in running speech" ([teens](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2012/04/teens.html)).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the pronunciation of this word may vary depending on the accent. (For example, compare the audio pronunciations of the [British](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/thirteen) and [American](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/thirteen#thirteen__3) versions at Collins.)

Accents aside, I think this has less to do with the word that follows and more to do with the overall context. For example:

> Bob: How long was your research paper?
>
> Tom: It was thirteen pages.
>
> Bob: Thirty pages?!
>
> Tom: No, I said, thir**teen**.

In that conversation, the word *thirteen* is enunciated with a much heavier emphasis on the second syllable the second time Tom says it, because clearly Bob misheard his friend the first time. Words like *thirty* and *thirteen*, or *fifty* and *fifteen*, are often misheard due to their similar pronunciation. So sometimes people will emphasize the -teen part to make sure they are not misheard:

> *Hurry up, everybody! The show is starting in four-TEEN minutes!*

Sometimes I've heard it said this way, when someone wants to make absolutely sure they've been heard correctly:

> *I want to order sixty pairs of socks – that's six zero socks. Sixty, not sixteen*.